# Opening a named pipe in bash, without reading or writing to it

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, shell, named-pipes

I want to use a named pipe in bash without reading or writing to it, until an event occurs. i need to keep this pipe open for the entire duration the shell script runs. I will read from it whenever I need to. Meaning, can something be done like this:

```
open(<$NAMED_PIPE>, "r+")
--do something--
--call child ruby script, which will write to named pipe--
--do something more---
read line < $NAMED_PIPE
```

Is this possible in bash?

I am using the following code:
../Ruby
|-- try1.rb
`-- try2.sh

try1.rb is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'optparse'

puts 'Hello World!, This is my first ruby program'

options = {}

optparse = OptionParser.new do|opts|

  opts.banner = "Featbuild minimal trial script for command line parsing"

  options[:cpl] = nil
  opts.on('--cpl SWITCH_STATE', 'compile on or off') do|cplopt|
      options[:cpl] = cplopt
      OPT_CPL=cplopt
      puts cplopt
  end

  opts.on('-h', '--help', 'Display this screen') do
    puts opts
    exit
  end
end

optparse.parse!

output = open("mypipe", "w+")

output.puts OPT_CPL
output.flush
```

And the try2.sh script(which calls the ruby script):

```
#!/bin/sh



mkfifo mypipe
exec 4< /home/yusufh/Ruby/mypipe

OPT=$*
./try1.rb ${OPT}


#read -ru 4 line
read line <&4

echo $line


exec 4<&- #close FIFO my_pipe

rm mypipe
```

@konsolebox, your solution worked when I used a normal text file where I copy the data from the ruby script, and from there itself the bash script picks it up.
However, On trying with named pipes, the bash script blocks after executing the following statement:`exec 4< /home/yusufh/Ruby/mypipe`. Control doesnt reach to spawning the ruby script process, where the data will be genrated, and after that the actual waiting/blocking by the bash script has to be done at this line: `read line <&4`.
Due to this, what I want to achieve isn't happening. Additional, when bash waits in when it acquires the fd of the FIFO, if I echo something into the named pipe on a duplicate terminal, it then does come out of wait and proceeds further. But then in this case, the data returned from the Ruby script is also not written to the FIFO, as I have observed. This is the output of the scritps in debug mode:

```
[yusufh@verigybuild6 Ruby]$ bash -xv try2.sh --cpl on &
[1] 2777
[yusufh@verigybuild6 Ruby]$ #!/bin/sh



mkfifo mypipe
+ mkfifo mypipe
exec 4< /home/yusufh/Ruby/mypipe
+ exec

[yusufh@verigybuild6 Ruby]$ echo "Hello World" > mypipe
[yusufh@verigybuild6 Ruby]$
OPT=$*
+ OPT='--cpl on'
./try1.rb ${OPT}
+ ./try1.rb --cpl on
Hello World!, This is my first ruby program
on


#read -ru 4 line
read line <&4
+ read line

echo $line
+ echo Hello World
Hello World


exec 4<&- #close FIFO my_pipe
+ exec

rm mypipe
+ rm mypipe



[1]+  Done                    bash -xv try2.sh --cpl on
[yusufh@verigybuild6 Ruby]$
```

Any ideas as why this is failing?. I appreciate the efforts! :-)

Comment: @Nehal I have searched for a soulution on stack overflow and google also, but couldn't find a satisfactory answer, so asking very specifically here...

Comment: @YusufHusainy You should call your ruby script first (in the background most probably) before running `exec` to open the named pipe. Naturally opening a named pipe blocks any process that does.

Comment: Also I don't remember that you can open a named pipe both for reading and writing. You just can do either reading or writing on one end: `w+` in `output = open("mypipe", "w+")` should probably be just `w`.

Comment: @konsolebox. Yes, that worked for, thanks a lot. The w+ is used to tell ruby that we are non-blocking write. Refer this [link]

  [link]:http://www.pauldix.net/2009/07/using-named-pipes-in-ruby-for-interprocess-communication.html

Comment: I'm not sure if that's correct. See the [open modes in ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-new). Or perhaps you're referring to a different open? Btw, welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty simple with Bash:

```
# Open the named pipe with a custom fd for input
exec 4< /path/to/named_pipe

# Do other things
:

# Read a line from pipe
read -ru 4 line

# Or
read -r line <&4

# Just make this consistent and close it when you're done. May not be necessary at exit but still a good practice.
exec 4<&-
```

- When reading input with `read`, it may be a good idea to use `-r` to prevent backslashes from escaping any character
- Running `read` with `IFS` unset (`IFS= read ...`) may also be helpful to prevent trimming of leading and trailing spaces.

Similar concept would apply for writing:

```
exec 4> /path/to/named_pipe
echo something >&4
exec 4>&-
```

Bonus: You may also open a named pipe in the scope of a block like `{}`, `while`, `for`, `if`, `until`, etc.. With it won't be necessary to close the file descriptor:

```
{
    # Do reads and other things
    ...
} 4< /path/to/named_pipe
```

Answer (score 0):

In absence of information about how your script rights to pipe, here is one possible option that i can think of.

1) open pipe `mkfifo /path/to/pipe`

2) do something `echo test1`

3) call child ruby script,which will write to named pipe (assuming script to be executable)  `/path/to/script >> /path/to/pipe &`

4) do something more `echo test2`

5) read line from pipe `read pipeddata < /path/to/pipe`